# Is there an equivalent numpy function to isin() that works row based?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

Say I have two numpy array's, for example:

```
arr1 = np.array([[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,3]])
```

and

```
arr2 = np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
```

What I want now is a function that compares the rows of `arr1` with the rows of `arr2` and outputs a list of the following shape

```
[True,False,True,False]
```

Where the first and second to last place are true since they represent a row in `arr1` that also appears in `arr2`.

I tried using `numpy.isin(arr1,arr2)` however that gives an array of shape `arr1` with the elements of `arr1` compared with the elements `arr2`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use broadcasting:

```
(arr1==arr2[:,None]).all(2).any(0)
```

output: `array([ True, False,  True, False])`

explanation:

- expand arr2 to an extra dimension:`arr2[:,None]`
- compare element-wise
- are `all` values True on the last dimension? (i.e, `[0,1]==[0,1]` needs to be `[True, True]`)
- is `any` of those aggregates True? (one of `[0,1]==[0,1]` (`True`) or `[0,1]!=[0,2]` (`False`) is sufficient)