# Python Delete a array from a array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i am trying delete a array from a array with numpy:

```
points = np.array([(25, 0), (0, 25), (0, 75), (25, 100), (75, 100), (100, 75), (100, 25), (75, 0)])
front_yard = np.array([(25, 0), (75, 0)])
```

when i try

```
new_coords = np.delete(points, front_yard)
```

it gaves:

```
IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 16
```

or

```
new_coords = np.delete(coords, np.where(coords == front_yard))
```

it gaves (doesnt work:

```
[ 25   0   0  25   0  75  25 100  75 100 100  75 100  25  75   0]
```

what should i do?

Comment: If you took time to actually read the `np.delete` docs, your errors would be obvious.  The `obj` argument is a position, not a value.  And without axis, it returns a flattened array.  Also anytime you try to use `np.where`, look at the result first.  You may even need to examine the `cond` array by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708091/is-there-an-equivalent-numpy-function-to-isin-that-works-row-based) answer to a similar question, you can use broadcasting to generate a boolean array, and then use it as a filter:

```py
points = np.array([(25, 0), (0, 25), (0, 75), (25, 100), (75, 100), (100, 75), (100, 25), (75, 0)])
front_yard = np.array([(25, 0), (75, 0)])

new_coords = points[~(points==front_yard[:,None]).all(2).any(0)]
```

`new_coords` will be:

```
array([[  0,  25],
       [  0,  75],
       [ 25, 100],
       [ 75, 100],
       [100,  75],
       [100,  25]])
```